# Как нужно прописывать slug в views.py и urls.py?

Tags: django

## models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', max_length=60)
text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст')
description = models.CharField(verbose_name='Описание', max_length=100)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True)
slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='URL', max_length=50, unique=True,)
image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Картинка', upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'alpha'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('guides/', views.GuidesView.as_view(), name='guides'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## views.py

```
from django.views import generic

from .models import Post, Guide


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'alpha/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_post_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:15]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'alpha/detail.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path('<slug>/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```